# CANON MP237 series driver for Ubuntu 20.01

Tags: drivers, xubuntu, printing, canon

Distro:Xubuntu
Connected throught:Usb Port
Maker:Canon
Model:MP237
OS version:20.01 focal fossa
Laptop Model:Acer Travelmate
BIOS:UEFI

How to find and install driver for my printer canon mp237 series?
I tried using printing model Generic(Recommended) and it really didnt work(wont print)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possibly a typo, but there was no Ubuntu release in 2020-January (ie. 20.01), and *focal* refers to 20.04 (2020-April release) which recently had it's 20.04.1 updated ISO released.

Comment: I am looking for a driver need for my Canon mp237 printer to work

Comment: I am lookin for a Canon mp237 driver any tips where ca I get it?

Comment: So far you've mentioned a non-existent release (2020-January) so I'd suggest you verify your stats & correct as per the first comment.

Comment: Ok.I reinsert the usb cable of the printer and xubuntu detects it.
"Canon mp230 series"
Upon trying to find a driver....it fails
im now left with 3 options
Recommended(Generic)
Or canon maker.
Im left with no direction as to what driver should i use.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you look at Canon's support website for this model?  They have a published printer driver... : https://id.canon/en/support/PIXMA%20MP237/model

Comment: Hi Nmath! Your suggestion helps.
I just had to know how to do this and im set!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so far,
I tried different ubuntu flavours(Ie,Ubuntu,Xubuntu,Lubuntu).
Lubuntu auto-detects my usb printer and gives me a driver for it to work.
This happens probably because of different sources and resources each distro uses.
I am satisfied that my printer works now.
Im quite frustrated as to why a usb printer won't work in 1 distro and work in another.
Is there a opportunity to contribute to this issue?

Comment: FYI:   All Ubuntu *flavors* (ie. Xubuntu & Lubuntu) use the exact same Ubuntu sources, with the exception that *flavors* use 'universe' by default (ie. community supported), but the Ubuntu server/desktop only use 'main' (which has a longer five year supported life ['universe' is supported only 3 years]. 'universe' can of course be enabled on Ubuntu Server/Desktop release - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu  They do of course include different packages on top of the Ubuntu based they all have (the difference between them is the desktop or GUI)

Comment: Ok,Got it thanks
I just want to contribute regarding to the driver for my CANON mp230 series.

Comment: Sorry I don't much about printer *drivers* nor how they work (Once I have the ppd/cups (*printer description*) file for my printers, I just save & add it if required). For helping with a project, most release notes provide a section that provides some links, eg. the Lubuntu 20.04.1 release notes has a "*How do I help?*" section https://lubuntu.me/focal-1-released/